# Could not find class 'org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher'

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I've been on an FTP odyssey for the past 4 or 5 days that is well documented in this question here: [FTP to 1and1.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157784/ftp-to-1and1-com)

At first I was just trying to upload a file, but now I've moved on to just seeing if I can get anything to work. I'm trying to list the files in the directory. I am getting a success response when changing directories and then I call the code below to list the contents.

```
FTPFile[] f =  mFtpClient.listFiles("/images_in");
for (FTPFile thisFile : f) {
    Log.e("FTPList", thisFile.getRawListing());
}
```

This is in a try/catch block but when it hits the first line the code goes in to AsyncTask.java and then the program crashes. The log output is below. It seems that I am missing a class called org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher. Is this a jar file that I will include in the project with an import statement or is it a java class file I will add like any other java class? I Googled it and found some Java class files that had a similar name but nothing definitive.

Greg

```
05-11 17:37:04.694    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher', referenced from method org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>
05-11 17:37:04.694    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1809 (Lorg/apache/oro/text/regex/Perl5Matcher;) in Lorg/apache/commons/net/ftp/parser/RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl;
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1804 (Lorg/apache/oro/text/regex/MalformedPatternException;)
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x1d
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/commons/net/ftp/parser/RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x001d
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/commons/net/ftp/parser/RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
05-11 17:37:04.704    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier rejected class Lorg/apache/commons/net/ftp/parser/RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl;
05-11 17:37:08.739    6518-6518/com.packagename.ftptest I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-11 17:37:10.120    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d0e18)
05-11 17:37:13.424    6518-6555/com.packagename.ftptest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.packagename.ftptest, PID: 6518
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/parser/RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createNTFTPEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:184)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2358)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2141)
        at com.packagename.ftptest.MainActivity$UpdateDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:196)
        at com.packagename.ftptest.MainActivity$UpdateDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:163)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: Its a library, so it would most likely be in a jar file.  Based on the name I'd look at apache's website.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Zip. Zilch. The closest I found on the Apache site was a Perl module, which was way more than a jar file. I searched a lot before posting and the only thing that comes close is on GrepCode, but is a class file displayed as a web page. That's why I asked if I was looking for a java class or a jar file.

Comment: Oro was killed as a project in 2010.  Here's the archive of their last version.  Not sure I'd recommend using it, but its an option:  http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/oro/

Comment: Sh*t. Then I must be also using an outdated version of Apache FTP. Maybe this is the root of all of my problems. How do i find the version of Import I am pointing to?

Comment: Unless there's an API to get it in the library I have no idea.  Here's the most recent version though:  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post an official answer about Oro being killed I'll accept it and up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use commons-net-3.6.jar in commons-net-3.6-bin.zip.